# How to hide a button when going back to previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a save button that saves the input data and a submit button that redirects to the next page. When this page first loads up, the submit button is hidden and when save is clicked, the submit button is visible and redirects to the next page when clicked. If users wants to edit the inputs, they can go back to the previous page where the inputs remain in the controls. My problem is that I want the submit button to be hidden when going to the previous page so that it forces users to save first. How do I do this?

Comment: post your html please.

Comment: Bit of a strange pattern. Why not have the submit button save the details **and** do the redirect?

Comment: I'm a bit confused: does your form has a SAVE button **AND** a SUBMIT button?

Comment: @DGibbs: It doesn't work when saving and redirecting at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

if you use serverside conttoller

```
if(IsPostback)

{

btn.Visible =false;
}
```

Comment: !ISPOSTBACK MEAN IF PAGE NOT REFRESHED DO SOMETHING

Comment: AND ISPOSTBACK IS MEAN IF PAGE ARE REFRESHED DO SOMETHING

Comment: The point is, neither works. To me Go Back is !IsPostBack, clicking a button is IsPostBack. Like I said, when the page first loads up, Btn.Visible=false works (preset=false). When Save is clicked, Btn.Visible=true works. This is IsPostBack. Anyway, I'm not after a tutorial, I'm looking for a way to hide Btn either before submit OR on return Go Back. I can put in a button so it is IsPostback but if users don't click it, then it's the same as not saving before submitting. I want to hide the submit button to force users to save before submitting. I hope that clarifies my OP.

Comment: PUT THAT IN PAGE LOAD

Comment: Show me, but quickly bring this to an end. This keeps going around in circles. You keep repeating yourself and I'm having to give you tutorials when I just want answers. It doesn't work. Try it and show code if you can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#TextBox1").val()) //if input has value
            $("#Button1").hide(); //hide button
    })
</script>
```

Server side code is not possible because on browser back no request is made, the page is retrieved from cache so it should be done with client code

Comment: I agree with server side not being possible. I'm testing this jquery approach, just having difficulties getting it to work. Thanks.

Comment: @matt2605 If you are using webforms $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").val() and $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").hide()

Comment: I'm looking into this client side coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
Page_Load()
{
   if(IsPostback)
  {
   btnSubmit.visible=false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web forms based application, try setting

btnSubmit.Visible = false in the Page_Load method

Comment: There's no request made. See TarekNajem. If it works for you, can you post the code?